# How do I transfer contacts from a Nokia 3110 to an Android using a Mac?

Tags: contacts, data-transfer

I have about 700 contacts on a Nokia 3110 handset that I want to transfer to my Android phone.

Transferring contacts via my SIM card is a slow process as I can only 200 do at a time. Moreover, I cannot be sure of which contacts have already been transferred.

Is there a faster way this can be achieved with a Mac?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NY15LWHF2mM

Comment: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Import-Contacts-to-Android-from-a-Nokia-Phone-146309.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a .vcf file on your SD card and copy that to your Android phone

Or

Using your SIM card when you copy contacts select 'move original' to SIM from phone

Or

Connect your handset to your pc via pc suite and sync. Connect your Android phone to your pc and transfer them to it

Answer (score 0):

First try syncing all your nokia's contacts to PhoneCopy. And then install Phonecopy to your android.And you are done.

http://www.phonecopy.com/

Comment: how can I upload my nokia 3110c contacts to Phonecopy ?

Comment: https://www.phonecopy.com/en/phones/view/nokia_3110_classic?referrer=Nokia

Comment: Instructions regarding the software in the link are required. Please note that we expect detailed answers not just drive-by answer-cum-comment. Also see [answer].